# Change Woocommerce checkout to process order on an separate WordPress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to create how Woocommerce handles orders so I can create an order on `Site A` and send that order to `Site B`.

So when customer adds items to their cart and click checkout, it creates the order on both `Site A` and `Site B`, however, it also redirects the user to `Site B` to process the payment.

So far I can only change the checkout button:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'my_change_checkout_url', 30 );

function my_change_checkout_url( $url ) {
   $url = "your checkout url ";
   return $url;
}
```

and creating the order.

```
if (isset($_POST['isOrder']) && $_POST['isOrder'] == 1) {
    $address = array(
        'first_name' => $_POST['notes']['domain'],
        'last_name'  => '',
        'company'    => $_POST['customer']['company'],
        'email'      => $_POST['customer']['email'],
        'phone'      => $_POST['customer']['phone'],
        'address_1'  => $_POST['customer']['address'],
        'address_2'  => '', 
        'city'       => $_POST['customer']['city'],
        'state'      => '',
        'postcode'   => $_POST['customer']['postalcode'],
        'country'    => 'NL'
    );

    $order = wc_create_order();
    foreach ($_POST['product_order'] as $productId => $productOrdered) :
        $order->add_product( get_product( $productId ), 1 );
    endforeach;

    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
    $order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );

    $order->calculate_totals();

    update_post_meta( $order->id, '_payment_method', 'ideal' );
    update_post_meta( $order->id, '_payment_method_title', 'iDeal' );

    // Store Order ID in session so it can be re-used after payment failure
    WC()->session->order_awaiting_payment = $order->id;

    // Process Payment
    $available_gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();
    $result = $available_gateways[ 'ideal' ]->process_payment( $order->id );

    // Redirect to success/confirmation/payment page
    if ( $result['result'] == 'success' ) {

        $result = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_payment_successful_result', $result, $order->id );

        wp_redirect( $result['redirect'] );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Though I'm not sure how to put all of this together so I can work with both Site A and Site B.

How can I do this?

EDIT: To explain more what I need this to do, I need to process payments on a second website, where it also has the products.

So, Customer buys product on Site A, after clicking "Pay with Paypal" (Instant Checkout) and "proceed with payment", the customer and it's information it filled is taken to Site B, where their either able to finalize the payment, OR be directly taken to the Paypal gateway on Site B.

Comment: Did you try with rest API?

Comment: Hi, didn't know woocommerce worked with the rest api, and I'm not sure how I'd do that.

Comment: This seams like a very bad idea.

Comment: I'm going to suggest that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), and that there's other better ways to approach the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Were you able to get this working?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way

Add this code in site A.

```
function action_woocommerce_new_order( $order_id ) { 

    //get all order details by $order_id    
    //post your data to site B

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://yoursiteB.com/wp-json/api/v2/create_wc_order");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "postvar1=value1&postvar2=value2");

    // In real life you should use something like:
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
    //          http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));

    // Receive server response ...
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);
}; 
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'action_woocommerce_new_order', 10, 1 );
```

Add this code in site B.

```
Class WC_Rest_API {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( $this, 'init_rest_api') );
    }

    public function init_rest_api() {
        register_rest_route('api/v2', '/create_wc_order', array(
           'methods' => 'POST',
           'callback' => array($this,'create_wc_order'),
        ));
   }

    public function create_wc_order( $data ) {

            //$data  - all the details needs to be send from site A

            global $woocommerce;
            $user_id = $data['user_id'];
            $user = get_user_by( 'ID', $user_id);
            $phonenumer = get_user_meta( $user_id,'user_phoneno', true);

            if($user) {         

                $address = array(
                  'first_name' => $user->display_name,
                  'last_name'  => $user->display_name,
                  'email'      => $user->user_email,
                  'phone'      => $phonenumer,            
                );

                $order = wc_create_order();
                //get product details from rest api site A
                $order->add_product(); 
                $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );

                $order->calculate_totals();         
                $order = wc_get_order( $order->id );

                $response['status'] = 'success';
                $response['message'] = 'Order created on wordpress site B.';    
                return new WP_REST_Response($response, 200);

          }

    }       
}

$rest_api = new WC_Rest_API();
```

Send all the data from site A to site B via below the URL.

http://yoursiteB.com/wp-json/api/v2/create_wc_order

Method should be 'POST'

Data should be contain all the details od order from site A.

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: What would the code look like to send from Site A to Site B?

Comment: You can use curl post

Comment: Hi @Vel

Can you give me steps how I can put this in place?

So what do I add to site A so I can change the place button to send the data to  site b? and on site b, how do i return the payment gateway url (redirecting to paypal)?

Comment: Okay, just not sure how i'd use your class and what i'd add to site a.

Comment: Hi Vel, sorry.

While this creates the order on SiteB, we also want to redirect to SiteB then complete the order there, or redirect to siteB with the order details, and then redirect to the Paypal gateway.

Is this possible?

Comment: While create the order in site B it will work with default

Comment: Sorry, I'm totally messing this up. What I pretty much want is a proxy. So customer on SiteA clicks add to cart or fills in their details. Clicks play with paypal.  Redirects to siteB where the customer is then redirected to the paypal gateway. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. Its possible. But its take sometime.

Comment: I dont have example. we need to write own script

Answer (score 0):

You can use the web hooks provided by the WooCommerce to update the **site B** about the product add and order creation.

[image: Woocommerce Web Hooks]

After that you can hook the checkout in **Site A** and redirect to the **Site B** checkout page.

https://metorik.com/blog/how-to-create-woocommerce-custom-redirects
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/

Comment: As this is a site for programmers, it would be most useful for you to expand a bit on how to use the webhooks, maybe include the relevant bits of code, etc.  Also - for the second part of your answer - that's a "link only" answer, which does not comply with Stackoverflow guidelines.  Instead, copy the relevant bits of code to your answer, in addition to the link....